# Redirect url to an url with md5 encoded filename

Tags: php, .htaccess, md5, redirect

I want to make a redirect, where I read the file's name and redirect to another url with encoded filename.

Example:
I open the http://example.org/something.png and it redirect me to http://newexample.org/437b930db84b8079c2dd804a71936b5f.png which is md5 coded.

Comment: And why are you doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

@Croises I can't speak for the OP but I'm looking for a solution to this as well. In my case it's for creating a rewrite for a caching system: saving the cached file as an md5 hash of the requested URI would allow me to cache more complex requests and redirect to them at the htaccess level.